# Ansible match inventory groups in role with dynamic inventory in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I have a dynamic inventory in GCP for app that runs on multiple VMs.
However I cannot seem to match any hosts with my playbook that calls a role.

The dynamic inventory creates groups with this naming convention, based on GCP labels and gpc.yml dynamic inventory file:

```
demo4_costing_db
demo4_costing_app
```

I can interrogate the entire inventory with `ansible-inventory --list -i gcp.yml`

Example output from the list command:

```yaml
"demo4_costing_db": {
        "hosts": [
            "10.10.60.194",
            "10.10.60.195",
            "10.10.60.196",
            "10.10.60.197",
            "10.10.60.198"
        ]
```

and so on, for various server functions in the app.

I then have a role that needs to do various disparate tasks to the different inventory groups.

The `tasks/main.yml` in the role looks like this:

```yaml
- name: "Install packages"
  ansible.builtin.dosomething
    action
  when: "'costing_db' in group_names"

- name: "Install Python packages"
  ansible.builtin.dosomethingelse
    different_action
  when: "'costing_app' in group_names"
```

the role is invoked with a playbook like this:
`ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i ../inventory/gcp-dynamic/demo4/gcp.yml --extra-vars "targets=demo4" -u ansible --key-file ~/ansible.pem --vault-password-file ~/.ansible/vault_pass.txt`

The deployment playbook looks like this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: root 
  
  roles:
   -  ../roles/postgres
```

Why does my playbook fail with no hosts matched?  From other examples of the `when:` conditional, I should be able to string-match on group names like that.

My inventory looks soemthing like this:
`ansible-inventory --list -i gcp.yml`

```
  "all": {
        "children": [
            "demo4_component_admin",
            "demo4_component_artemis",
            "demo4_component_batch",
            "demo4_component_discovery",
            "demo4_component_elastic",
            "demo4_component_gateway",
            "demo4_component_inbox",
            "demo4_component_tools",
            "demo4_component_transfer",
            "demo4_costing_app",
            "demo4_costing_db",
            "demo4_inventory_demo4",
            "demo4_schema_artemisdb",
            "demo4_schema_batchdb",
            "demo4_schema_gatewaydb",
            "demo4_schema_inboxdb",
            "demo4_schema_transferdb",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Why are you passing "{{ targets }}_inventory_{{ targets }}" to the hosts argument in each play? Isn't different from the naming convention you've explained?

Comment: For your specific launch example: `{{ targets }}_inventory_{{ targets }}` evaluates to `demo4_inventory_demo4` <= is there a group with that name in your inventory?

Comment: @HoussemAZZOUZ I think you are correct, I have changed the "hosts:" speficiation from that string to "all", which should now simply scan my dynamic inventory and be able to do the string matching with my "when:" statements, but I am still not able to match any hosts. I will update the main post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: `when: "'costing_db' in group_names"` <= do you have a group named exactly `costing_db` that your target can be part of? Since answer is no, this condition will never match. Why do you do this anyway ? Create a play targeting `demo4_costing_db` and an other targeting `demo4_costing_app` (in the play's `hosts:` section) and put the relevant tasks for each group in each play. If you need to run tasks on both groups at once, simply have an other play targeting both groups (i.e. `hosts: "demo4_costing_app:demo4_costing_db"`

Comment: About why it does not match, short version: your can run the `in` test against a string or an iterable (e.g. a list). `substring in string` maches a substring anywhere in the string. `element in list` matches one specific and entire element inside a list. `group_names` is a list of group names (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html). So `'toto' in group_names` will only match if one element contains the exact string `"toto"`.

Comment: thanks @Zeitounator that makes sense about the string matching. The reason I was not simply using a 'hosts' statement in the role is that I found that the 'hosts' statement was not being allowed in the role , in tasks/main.yml.  I can try to split this out to multiple roles with targeted hosts.